# Bug bootstrap with select

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootsrap for net core project. Now I have a problem with displaying select, which has class custom-select.
[image: Here is the select]

[image: Code for select]

I need to have only one down arrow in select.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer. Just need to add this style.

```
.custom-select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: you cannot answer to your own question.

Comment: I asked, because i didn't know what is the problem, but when I have found answer, I answered my question for others.

Comment: May be you should have waited for someone to answer, or should posted as community